# Memory leak when inserting elements in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtreewidget

When I insert elements into a `QTreeWidget`, I allocate memory for both `QStringList` and `QTreeWidgetItem`

```
QStringList *temp;
while(other_elements)
{
    temp = new QStringList();
    temp->push_back("first_field");
    temp->push_back("second_field");

    items.append(new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, *temp));

    element_iterator++;
}

myTreeWidget->insertTopLevelItems(0, items);
```

I read that `QTreeWidgetItem` is automatically deallocated when the `clear()` function is called, but what about the `QStringList`? Is it a memory leak?

Comment: to avoid this you can use the overloaded `operator<<` to do that you just call `items.append(new QTreeWidgetItem(0, QStringList() << "first_field" << "second_field");`

soo long zai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will leak, but not for the reason you think.

The `QStringList` that the `QTreeWidgetItem` maintains will be deleted with the tree item - that's going to work fine.

**But** the `temp` you're allocated will not. When you pass that `*temp` to the constructor, the item stores a *copy* of that. The object you allocated is still alive and well after the constructor call - and since you're not deleting it, it is leaked.

Change your code to the following to avoid the leak and unnecessary heap allocation:

```
while(other_elements)
{
    QStringList temp;
    temp.push_back("first_field");
    temp.push_back("second_field");

    items.append(new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, temp));

    element_iterator++;
}
```